# Does anyone know of a VB(A/6) example using GetLocaleInfoEx?

Tags: c++, winapi, vba, vb6

I thought I dug most of what I need out of the header files, but I keep crashing out.
Here is the declare I tried using, but I don't think it's just an issue of the declare. I think I'm actually using it wrong.

```
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoEx Lib "kernel32" ( _
ByVal lpLocaleName As Long, _
ByVal LCType As Long, _
ByRef lpLCData As Long, _
ByVal cchData As Long _
) As Long
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the corresponding documentation.
**EDIT by MarkJ**: Oorang wants to use GetLocaleInfoEx because the MSDN docs say it is preferred on Vista.

Comment: A possible pitfall is the locale name. What your Declare look like?

Comment: Congratulations, you are the one and only Google hit for "LocaleInfoEx".  That does explain the crash perhaps.

Comment: @RS Conley, amongst others... Yes.

Comment: Can you post some code for an example call too? What "crash" do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I couldn't test this because I don't have Vista here at home, but Oorang says it works (in the comments).

```
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoEx _
Lib "kernel32" ( _ 
  ByVal lpLocaleName As Long, _ 
  ByVal LCType As Long, _ 
  ByVal lpLCData As Long, _ 
  ByVal cchData As Long _ 
  ) As Long 

Const LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1 = 56&
Dim sLocaleName As String 
Dim sRetBuffer As String 
Dim nCharsRet As Long 
sLocaleName = "en-US" & Chr$(0) 
sRetBuffer = Space(256) 
nCharsRet = GetLocaleInfoEx(StrPtr(sLocaleName), _ 
  LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1, StrPtr(sRetBuffer), Len(sRetBuffer)-1)
MsgBox Left$(sRetBuffer, nCharsRet)
```

Your original Declare looked wrong to me. You are required to provide a buffer for the return string (wide characters, otherwise known as a UTF-16 Unicode string). You need to pass a pointer to the buffer in the `lpLCData` argument. So you [need to declare](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/varptr.asp) that argument as `ByVal Long` and use `StrPtr(string)` where `string` has been filled with characters to make room for the return data.